# Google image scraper in Apify using the extended output function

Tags: web-scraping, apify

In Apify -
Google Shopping Scraper - emastra/google-shopping-scraper
does not scrape images.

Over here - https://github.com/apify-projects/store-google-search-scraper/issues/84

Tells me how.

But it didn't work, because I don't understand it.
Here are my results when I plug it into the Extended output function:
[A simple log showing an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThnfT.png)

So I tried fixing it by forcing results. Here was my theory that ended up failing:

```
async ({ label, Apify, $, request }) => {
    if (label === 'HANDLE' && request.url.includes('tbm=isch')) { // image tab
        // dataset will be full of { data: 'base64', link: 'https://...' }
       const result = await Apify.pushData(
            $('[jsname="r5xl4"] > [jsaction]').map((_, el) => {
                const $el = $(el)
                return {
                    data: $el.find('img[src^="data"]').attr('src'),
                    link: $el.find('>a[href]').attr('href'),
                }
            }).get()
        )
    }
    return result
}
```

And the results are as follows:

```
2022-11-17T04:08:07.813Z ACTOR: Pulling Docker image from repository.
2022-11-17T04:08:19.700Z ACTOR: Creating Docker container.
2022-11-17T04:08:21.974Z ACTOR: Starting Docker container.
2022-11-17T04:08:23.198Z Starting X virtual framebuffer using: Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x720x16 -nolisten tcp
2022-11-17T04:08:23.200Z Executing main command
2022-11-17T04:08:25.043Z INFO  System info {"apifyVersion":"2.3.2","apifyClientVersion":"2.6.0","osType":"Linux","nodeVersion":"v16.17.0"}
2022-11-17T04:08:25.411Z INFO  Search URLs:
2022-11-17T04:08:25.412Z    http://www.google.com/search?q=iPhone&tbm=shop&tbs=vw:l
2022-11-17T04:08:25.581Z INFO  Starting crawler.
2022-11-17T04:08:25.640Z INFO  PuppeteerCrawler:AutoscaledPool: state {"currentConcurrency":0,"desiredConcurrency":2,"systemStatus":{"isSystemIdle":true,"memInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.2,"actualRatio":null},"eventLoopInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.6,"actualRatio":null},"cpuInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.4,"actualRatio":null},"clientInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.3,"actualRatio":null}}}
2022-11-17T04:08:37.551Z INFO  Processing: http://www.google.com/search?q=iPhone&tbm=shop&tbs=vw:l
2022-11-17T04:08:37.552Z INFO  Number of page: 1
2022-11-17T04:08:37.605Z INFO  Found 12 products on the page.
2022-11-17T04:08:37.669Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:37.746Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:37.816Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:37.852Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:37.895Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:37.939Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:37.980Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.036Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.083Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.135Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.197Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.243Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.276Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.324Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.355Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.397Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.442Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.482Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.521Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.564Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.601Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.694Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.728Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.762Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.802Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.861Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.907Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.947Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:38.981Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.015Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.071Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.142Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.182Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.224Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.266Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.301Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.333Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.371Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.425Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.460Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.493Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.837Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.878Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:39.932Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.009Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.054Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.186Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.223Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.296Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.364Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.405Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.454Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.507Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.612Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.651Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.693Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.738Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.773Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.804Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.852Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.891Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.943Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:40.980Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:41.015Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:41.050Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:41.110Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:41.140Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:41.176Z INFO  extendOutputFunctionfailed. Returning default output. Error: ReferenceError: result is not defined
2022-11-17T04:08:41.228Z INFO  0 items on the page were successfully scraped.
2022-11-17T04:08:41.349Z INFO  PuppeteerCrawler: All the requests from request list and/or request queue have been processed, the crawler will shut down.
2022-11-17T04:08:41.577Z INFO  PuppeteerCrawler: Final request statistics: {"requestsFinished":1,"requestsFailed":0,"retryHistogram":[1],"requestAvgFailedDurationMillis":null,"requestAvgFinishedDurationMillis":14044,"requestsFinishedPerMinute":4,"requestsFailedPerMinute":0,"requestTotalDurationMillis":14044,"requestsTotal":1,"crawlerRuntimeMillis":15998}
2022-11-17T04:08:41.579Z INFO  Crawler Finished.
```

So. I am out of ideas. Anybody know what to do?

So I think I made some progress...
I put in this:

```
 async ($) => {
    result = {
                 data: "test",
                 link:"test",
             };
    if (true) { // image tab
        // dataset will be full of { data: 'base64', link: 'https://...' }
        result =
            $('[jsname="r5xl4"] > [jsaction]').map((_, el) => {
                const $el = $(el)
                return {
                    data: $el.find('img[src^="data"]').attr('src'),
                    link: $el.find('>a[href]').attr('href'),
                }
            }).get()
       
    }
    return result
}
```

and got:

```
2022-12-02T17:37:24.077Z ACTOR: Pulling Docker image from repository.
2022-12-02T17:37:34.147Z ACTOR: Creating Docker container.
2022-12-02T17:37:34.672Z ACTOR: Starting Docker container.
2022-12-02T17:37:35.658Z Starting X virtual framebuffer using: Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x720x16 -nolisten tcp
2022-12-02T17:37:35.659Z Executing main command
2022-12-02T17:37:36.715Z INFO  System info {"apifyVersion":"2.3.2","apifyClientVersion":"2.6.0","osType":"Linux","nodeVersion":"v16.17.0"}
2022-12-02T17:37:37.011Z INFO  Search URLs:
2022-12-02T17:37:37.012Z    http://www.google.com/search?q=iPhone&tbm=shop&tbs=vw:l
2022-12-02T17:37:37.178Z INFO  Starting crawler.
2022-12-02T17:37:37.230Z INFO  PuppeteerCrawler:AutoscaledPool: state {"currentConcurrency":0,"desiredConcurrency":2,"systemStatus":{"isSystemIdle":true,"memInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.2,"actualRatio":null},"eventLoopInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.6,"actualRatio":null},"cpuInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.4,"actualRatio":null},"clientInfo":{"isOverloaded":false,"limitRatio":0.3,"actualRatio":null}}}
2022-12-02T17:37:48.057Z INFO  Processing: http://www.google.com/search?q=iPhone&tbm=shop&tbs=vw:l
2022-12-02T17:37:48.058Z INFO  Number of page: 1
2022-12-02T17:37:48.068Z INFO  Found 63 products on the page.
2022-12-02T17:37:48.158Z ERROR
2022-12-02T17:37:48.159Z   Error: extendOutputFunction must return an object!
2022-12-02T17:37:48.159Z       at applyFunction (/home/myuser/src/utils.js:45:23)
2022-12-02T17:37:48.160Z       at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
2022-12-02T17:37:48.160Z       at async Object.exports.SEARCH_PAGE (/home/myuser/src/routes.js:102:20)
2022-12-02T17:37:48.161Z       at async wrap (/home/myuser/node_modules/apify/node_modules/@apify/timeout/index.js:73:27)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code, the error log is saying where is the issue: `result is not defined` - that is because you are defining the `result` variable in the `if (...) {...}` block, and after that block ends, the variable goes out of scope, so you can't access (and therefore return) it. A solution for that would be to define it before the block, and only assign a value inside, so something like this:

```js
async (args) => {
  let result = "";
  if (condition) {
    result = // ... more code
  }
  return result
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but Apify generally uses the convention that user-supplied `extendOutput` functions should return an object that is then merged with the data scraped by the scraper itself, and you shouldn't directly call `Apify.pushData` (I'm not sure what the linked GitHub issue where you found this code wants to say). So for example, if a scraper scrapes `{productName: "iPhone 11", url: "https://example.com"}` and your `extendOutputFunction` returns `{imageData: "base64", imageLink: "https://example.com/image.jpg"}`, the final output will contain all these four properties, i.e. `{productName: "iPhone 11", url: "...", imageData: "...", imageLink: "..."}`.

The log for the second piece of code that you tried also says what you're doing wrong: `extendOutputFunction must return an object`, but `$(...).map(...).get()` returns an array (see [cheerio docs](https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html#get.get-2)). If you want just the first item, use `.get(0)`

Comment: Thank you for your point on the ".get()", very much appreciated. However, my results did not merge the images, and I don't understand what you mean by an if block. I tried googling is "If" a block, and apparently it is not...

Comment: Okay, it's a block. But it's not a scope... We didn't declare a variable, so that makes it global.
> if(true){
>  foo = "test" //this is global
> }
> console.log(foo)//returns test